# How can I add a block to the order page in the Back Office?

Tags: admin, orders

I just recently started learning Magento, so do not judge me asking a stupid question.

I read the [documentation](http://tutorialsformagento.blogspot.com/2014/06/add-custom-fields-to-order-and-quote.html) and do everything step by step. Now I got to the last point (Step 4) and I can not do it. I do not understand in what directory to place the files described in step 4. Can you help? Thank.

Please, I'm just learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below I am providing you a quick directory location references

```
Admin Layout Update XML File :- app\design\adminhtml\default\default\layout\custom.xml
Order Block File :- app\code\local\Easylife/ThirdParty/Block/Adminhtml/Order.php
Order PHTML File :- app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\custom/order.phtml
Info PHTML File :- app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\custom/sales/order/info.phtml
```

**Note :-** Here I assume the module resides in `local` codePool.